# App icon for Android play store

Tags: android, coronasdk, appimage

My app Trump Attack by Verma Empire is on the playstore but for some reason once you download the app, and then you look for it on your device, the app shows up but it says icon on the image, there is no image! I filled out all the necessary graphics on the store listing for my app for playstore but why does the image for the app icon say icon, and not show an actual image even though i filled out all the necessary graphic son the store listing?

Just a side not, my app was built through corona sdk.

Answer (score 2):

From Corona SDK doc

> Before deploying an app, you should design the proper app icons for
>   the targeted platforms. These icons should be designed at the sizes
>   specified below and exported in the .png format. To avoid potential
>   incompatibilities, these images should also be non-interlaced and they
>   shouldn't contain an embedded ICC profile.
>
> Icon image files should be included in the project's base directory —
>   the build system may not locate files placed in a subfolder.

File name and size for icons on Android

- Icon-xxxhdpi.png  192 × 192
- Icon-xxhdpi.png   144 × 144
- Icon-xhdpi.png    96 × 96
- Icon-hdpi.png 72 × 72
- Icon-mdpi.png 48 × 48
- Icon-ldpi.png 36 × 36

Read more about it [in documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/buildSettings/index.html#appicons) and see [Icon generator for Corona SDK](http://icon.angrymarmot.org).

Answer (score 1):

The app's icon as it appears in the store is not defined by the app store settings.  The app store settings only influence what your app looks like on the store page.  The actual icon for the device is baked into the manifest file inside the APK.

I'm not familiar with Corona, but your build should have something called `AndroidManifest.xml` within it that defines the metadata for the app.  That includes the required permissions, starting Activity, and the icon for the application.

It might look something like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourname.yourapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

That attribute line within it:

```
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
```

specifies the resource name of the image to use as the icon